# changing the appearance of output using lapply function

Tags: r, lapply

I used lapply function in the following code.

```
library(bio3d)
files <- list.files('/home/sanvi/Desktop/folder', '.*\\.pdb$', full.names=TRUE)
rgs <- lapply(files, function(x) {
    data <- read.pdb(x)
    mass <- rep(12, length(data$xyz)/3)
    rgyr(data, mass)
})
rgs

[[1]]
[1] 32.56132

[[2]]
[1] 11.83162
```

I would like to get the output as shown below.

```
filename1.pdb    32.56132
filename2.pdb    11.83162
```

Are there any way to get the output as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `stack` after naming the `list` ('rgs') with the `basename` of 'files'.  This will output a two column 'data.frame'

```
stack(setNames(rgs, basename(files)))
#            ind   values
#1 filename1.pdb 32.56132
#2 filename2.pdb 11.83162
```

#### data

```
rgs <- list(32.56132, 11.83162)
files <- paste("/home/sanvi/Desktop/folder", 
     c("filename1.pdb", "filename2.pdb"), sep="/")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!